# Is there a better way to handle null exceptions for deeply nested data?

Tags: java, spring, performance, java-8, nullpointerexception

I wonder whether there is a better way of handling nulls for deeply nested data? 
Lets say i have 4 classes namely **University**, **Branch**, **Student**, **Information** nested one around other.

```
class University{
Branch branch;
//getters & setters
}
class Branch{
Student student;
//getters & setters
}
class Student{
Information information;
//getters & setters
}
class Information{
String name;
List<Boolean> attendance;
//getters & setters
}
```

For some reason, i want student Name to be consumed, for which we just navigate 
`university.getBranch().getStudent().getInformation().getName()`
which is prone to raise null exceptions.
For that reason we always put an `if` block around it to check nulls,Something like this
 `if(university != null && university.getBranch() != null ..... )`
Above the nested depth is 4, sometimes i have depth more than 8 or 9. In those situations, something like above doesn't make sense, we are rather sacrificing clean code.
I need a better approach for this problem 

Below are few ways i found helpful with their own limitations:

1. **PropertySource**.getNestedProperty() - Apache common *beanUtils* library, which almost worked for me except it throws `NestedNullException` which needs to be handled using `try{}catch(){}` which for some reason, we don't want to do. Even have issues when dealing with lists.
2. **Optionals** - Java 8 provides final Class Optional

```
*Traditional Way :*
if (university != null) {
    Branch branch = user.getBranch();
    if (branch != null) {
        Student student = branch.getStudent();
        if (student != null) {
            Information info = student.getInformation();
            if (info != null) {
                name = info.getName();
            }
        }
    }
}

*Java 8 Optionals :*
Optional<String> optional = Optional.ofNullable(user)
  .flatMap(University::getBranch)
  .flatMap(Branch::getStudent)
  .map(Student::getInformation)
  .orElse("default");
```

Code looks much clean now except we need to create an object for every Optional(if we want to use that optional more than once)

3. The Third way of doing is **JSONfying** entire object using Object Mapper and get that data directly

```
responseEntityJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(responseEntity);
        rootNode = objectMapper.readTree(responseEntityJson);
        DataValue = rootNode.findValue("Data");
```

I'm looking forward to know your opinions.

Comment: Maybe you could try avoiding `null`s in the first place? If that's not possible, I'd personally go for the `Optional` approach.

Comment: At least in my case, nulls are inevitable. We deal with some older microservices which were neither written by us nor will be rewritten. Yeah i need to research a bit more on Optional. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, it is best to avoid the possibility of null values for as many kinds of objects as possible.

For example, if your university has a list/set of students, `getStudents()` should never return `null`. It may return an empty collection, though. If the `University` class makes sure that `getStudents()` never return `null`, you can skip the null checks for `getStudents()` wherever you call it.

Also, for many other values that can be received by getters, they should logically never be null, so just let the object make sure it never returns null. If the field is immutable, you can check in the constructor for null values and later be sure that you never receive `null`.

If something can really be absent, `Optional` is a good alternative.

Comment: Yeah, i agree with you, but at least in my case, nulls are inevitable. We deal with some older microservices which were neither written by us nor will be rewritten. Yeah i need to research a bit more on Optional. Thanks :)